# What anova do i use

Tags: anova

So for an assignment, I am looking at how plant foliage health (ranked on a scale of 0-5, 0 meaning the foliage is all dead, 5 meaning the foliage is all alive) has changed over time (I have data from 2008 and 2023) as an indicator of population health. It has been a while since I have done statistics so any help on what analysis is best would really be appreciated

Comment: you don't need an ANOVA here since you have only two groups. Is the 'foliage health' continuously measured on does it only take values in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ ?

Comment: it is categorical. each plant is placed into one of the categories (0-5)

Comment: would a t-test be better suited to this type of analysis?

Comment: hmm, no you variable it's on an ordinal scale thus you have to use some rank-based test s.t. the Wilcoxon test for two samples.

Comment: Are the data paired ?  That is, is it the same plots measured in 2008 and 2023, recorded such that you know which plot is which ?